# How to setup pyspark properly in windows 11?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm just new to using Spark so I did the following (**NOTE**: Im using Windows 11):

- I already have python 3.10 installed (located in: `C:\Program Files\Python)`.
- I installed Java jdk 17.0.1 (located in `C:\Program Files\Java)`.
- I installed apache spark 3.2.0  (located in `C:\Program Files\Spark)`.
- I installed winutils from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe (located in `C:\Program Files\Hadoop\bin)`.

My environment variables look like this:

[image]

**So I ran this test code in VS code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('project1').getOrCreate()

print(spark)
```

I received this:

```
C:\Users\eigenaar\Desktop\Python>"C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" c:/Users/eigenaar/Desktop/Python/Python/test.py
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/10/24 11:29:09 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\eigenaar\Desktop\Python\Python\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('project1').getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1573, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


C:\Users\eigenaar\Desktop\Python>SUCCESS: The process with PID 9284 (child process of PID 3596) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3596 (child process of PID 18880) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 18880 (child process of PID 5300) has been terminated.
```

Comment: You're getting a Java error. Spark does not support above Java 11. Nor do I think Python 3.10 (at least not yet)

Comment: Put Spark in Docker (bitnami distribution); Map the sparkfiles with a volume to Host; develop on Windows (PyCharm-free?) and spark-submit in the Container. Then you don't need to install all that stuff on your Windows machine (apart from Docker)

Comment: @BertC I dont have any experience in Docker

Comment: @OneCricketeer So Should I install Python 3.9 and install Java JDK version  < 11 ?

Comment: Read the Spark website. It tells you what versions are supported